# Unable to break up what nested functions are doing

Tags: python, list, function, return, return-value

I'm having trouble understanding how this nested function is returning values in the list below. It's unclear which function gets used first in the code below:

```
def f(xs):
     def g(ys):
          return ys[::-1]
     return [x-2+(2*7/4) for x in g(xs[:-2])]
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

[6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5]
```

Comment: Functions are first defined with `def` and then later called by their name, passing in arguments. So we can see that `g` is defined inside `f` (meaning it gets re-defined every time that `f` is called). We can see that `g` is only called inside `f`, at  `g(xs[:-2])]`, and the `f` is called outside of both (as it must be) in `f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])`

Comment: In this case it's doing the same thing it would do if it was not nested and was also passed `xs` as an argument (instead of referencing the one passed to `f()`).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple:

inside your function `f`, is defined a function `g`

It's not different to do in this way:

```
def g(ys):
     return ys[::-1]

def f(xs):
     return [x-2+(2*7/4) for x in g(xs[:-2])]
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

But in your situation you are defining `g` inside `f`, **while executing f**. Usually you would define the function inside your other function if you need something custom, based on the main function

Anyway this is the flow:

1. `f` is executed
2. `g` is defined while `f` is executed
3. `g` is called while `f` is executed
4. `f` returns the value obtained thanks to `g`

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the individual steps.
Having your input list defined,

```
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

your function

```
def g(ys):
    return ys[::-1]
```

basically inverts the input list, i.e. it returns `[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` when given `xs.

In your function

```
def f(xs):
     def g(ys):
          return ys[::-1]
     return [x-2+(2*7/4) for x in g(xs[:-2])]
```

you only give `xs[:-2]` (`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`) to `g` which then returns `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. Thus `f` basicaly returns

```
[x-2+(2*7/4) for x in 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])]
```

which should be what you gave

```
[6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 3.5, 2.5]
```

The functions are executed in the following order.

1. `f` is called, which defines `g` (only locally inside `f`)
2. `g` gets called inside `f`
3. the result of `f` is computed and returned after execution of `g` is done.